# PHP Form to Email Array

Tags: php, forms

Having some trouble with this. I have an array that is inputting my form data ro email but trying to get a way to combine some check boxes. For "Grips" there are a few check boxes that I would like listed if checked. Below is the pieces of code (this is just the relevant chunk of the PHP, the form mailer works great just cant get all the check boxs to post):

```
$grind = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind"]);

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"AccountName"} = "Accounts's Name:  "; 
 $fields{"FitterName"} = "Fitter's Name:  "; 
 $fields{"CustomerCat"} = "__CUSTOMER INFO___"; 
 $fields{"CustomerName"} = "Customer's Name:  ";
 $fields{"CustomerPhone"} = "Customer's Phone:  ";
 $fields{"CustomerAddress"} = "Customer's Address:  ";
 $fields{"CustomerCity"} = "Customer's City:  ";
 $fields{"CustomerState"} = "Customer's State;  ";
 $fields{"CustomerZip"} = "Customer's Zip:  ";
 $fields{"WedgeType"} = "Wedge Loft:  ";
 $fields{"$grind"} = "Wedge Grind:  " ;
 $fields{"WedgesShaft"} = "Wedge Shaft:  ";
```

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="grind[V-Grind]" class="grinds" value="V-Grind">V-Grind
<input type="checkbox" name="grind[Tour Grind]" class="grinds" value="Tour Grind">Tour Grind
<input type="checkbox" name="grind[Heal Grind]" class="grinds" value="Heal Grind">Heal Grind
<input type="checkbox" name="grind[No Grind]"  class="grinds"value="No Grind">No Grind
```

I know that this `$fields{"$grind"} = "Wedge Grind:  " ;` is not the right way to pass the array at top from $grind but not sure what would be the proper way since everything else works great.

Comment: You want to access your array like this: $fields['AccountName'] = 'foo'; If you enable error reporting & error display on your server PHP will output error messages explaining the problem.

Comment: All the fields work fine except for `$fields{"$grind"} = "Wedge Grind:  " ;`. I know that is not the correct way to retrieve the info from `$grind = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind"]);` Just not sure how to do it in the `$fields['ID'] = 'EMail Output';` form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will correctly implode the array with comma separation. But you're using the POSTed values to name the array element's key. This is not going to help you build the e-mail.

For example, if the user selects "Heal Grind" and "Tour Grind", then your code creates:

```
$fields{"Heal Grind, Tour Grind"} = "Wedge Grind:  ";
```

So the POSTed values are stored in the key, which doesn't seem very logical to me. Why not make it:

```
$fields{"WedgeGrind"} = "Wedge Grind: " . $grind;
```

Then in the e-mail, when you reference this field, it'll create:

```
Wedge Grind: Heal Grind, Tour Grind
```

Your values POST correctly. Since you didn't supply the full code, I'm not sure how you're trying to build the e-mail, but storing the values in the array key is not usually how it's done. It seems more logical to use the second example and build the e-mail using that.

Also you have a checkbox option for "No Grind," but the user could also select any of the other grind options plus "No Grind." So if you receive an order for "No Grind" and "V-Grind," that would confuse you (I just assume) and you would need to follow up with the customer to verify the order. Rather, you can make the grind checkboxes optional and remove the "No Grind" option, that way if no grind is POSTed, you know no grind is desired.

Unless the customer may be ordering multiple items with a different grind for each, then the existing system makes sense, though it could be improved a bit if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense to me, also on the "No Grind" part. I just put in the code `$fields{"WedgeGrind"} = "Wedge Grind: " . $grind;` which i thought would work but the email just displays `Wedge Grind: `. Not sure if the `$grind = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind"]);` and HTML are the cause.

Comment: I don't know your full implementation so I don't know if there is any error further down the line, but this stripped down bit works fine. Can't post the HTML due to the comment being too long, but if you put your checkbox form below this, select some options, and submit, this will create the array element and output it. Working for me.

`<?
if ($_POST) {
    $grind = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind"]);
    
    $fields = array();
    $fields{"WedgeGrind"} = "Wedge Grind: " . $grind;
    echo $fields{"WedgeGrind"};
}
?>`

Comment: Thanks for some reason it is working now. Might have taken a bit to update. Thanks a lot!